# Calling an web server with post getting an internal server error

Tags: c#, .net, api, console-application

getting error with post to api tring to get json list back

```
string apiUrl = "https://expample.com/api.asmx/Agency_ListNewAndModifiedOrders";

 var input = new
            {
                SecurityCode = "xxx123",
                LastModifiedMinutes = 60,
                ExcludePerDiem = false,
                ExcludeContracts = false,
                ExcludePermPlacement = false
            };

            string inputJson = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(input);

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            string json = client.UploadString(apiUrl, inputJson);
```

then getting error 500

System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.'

Comment: Just as the message states, there was an error *on the remote server*, not in your code.  Your request may have been malformed in some way, but we can't know that because we don't maintain that remote server.  If no further information is present in the response, you may need to contact whoever does maintain that remote server.

Answer (score 1):

This simply means that there was an error in the server that you sent the post to. If you have access to the server, you could investigate or debug there.